# Nest C-wire issues with old boiler, xfmr, and 8124 aquastat

Tags: thermostat, nest, aquastat

I have my C & Rc connected to my old 28vac xfmr and my W & Rh directly to T & T on aquastat. I added the Rc so the Nest would stay active in Summer when boiler is turned off. This setup worked fine for a year or two. This past January, the Nest was showing "Delayed for 2.xx minutes" and would shut off call for heat and then show "Delayed..." before resuming. Turning boiler off/on/off every few minutes !
I reset to factory settings and turned off TruRadiant and it was fine until mid April it started again. In checking my wiring, I see the xfmr now has 28.3vac (previously noted 23.4vac). I also noticed when the thermostat is displaying "Delayed.." I can turn it up a single click, not even one degree, and the message goes away. Any thoughts would be appreciated. BTW - I do have another xfmr nearby for doorbells that could be an alternate source for the C ?

Comment: Your wiring sounds correct.  If it worked for a year or two it obviously is doing what it is supposed to.  The Nest specs say 20 to 30 V.   28 is high, why aren't you using a more typical 24V supply?  Esp. as you have one.  Maybe yours is triggering a reject mechanism in the Nest as it approaches 30V.  Just a guess.    Maybe touching the controls resets it if the supply is at acceptable levels when you touch them.  This is all guessing about undocumented edge functionality.

Comment: The xfmr voltage does seem to be the only thing that changed since I previously noted 23.4. I've been using the xfmr that's connected to the boiler's aquastat but I could try to switch the C & Rc to the doorbell xfmr to see of the 28.3 is causing the problem.

Comment: From my hasty reading, "Delayed" means voltage too low, it does not mean too high.  You should call Nest to find out if there are undocumented ways to produce the message.  You should also determine if your aquastat transformer becomes unpowered under any circumstances.    I just noticed you say "in the summer when boiler is turned off" ... do you remove power to the boiler, or just turn down the thermostat?  Maybe the aquastat is only powered when the boiler is powered, perhaps even only when there is call for heat.

Comment: I have a switch on the boiler that shuts her down without killing power to my xmfr. The xfmr is old so I may try using my doorbell xfmr before heating season is over (ability to test). Everthing I find on Google points to C wire .. assumes you don't have one and battery got low .. my battery voltage seems fine at 3.95v. I'm afraid Google Nest will tell me to call a pro in installer .. not at their expense I'm sure :(

Comment: Maybe, so tell them you are working on a customer's thermostat and need help with a strange situation.  Power exists, supplied voltage and battery voltage all good, display says Delayed.

Comment: I called Nest and they were nice but guided me thru the factory reset again in search of a message code that might better explain the "delayed.." dilemma. No code appeared so .. the mystery remains and unit is out of warranty. Especially odd is the fact that the "delayed.." message goes away if I rotate the setting .. ever so slightly, less than 1° ! Now, if I'm away and happen to have same indication on my phone, I should be able to bump it by 1°. Problem is the phone app doesn't always show "delayed.." when unit does so. I will also run another pair of wires to doorbell xfmr to rule that out

Comment: Experiment to see if a temporary power drop causes this.  Remove power for a few hours, see if you can provoke "Delayed" on purpose.  Then return power and see if it goes away.  If not, see if it goes away when you touch the dial.